# Things that cannot be done with npm as a build tool?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build-process

I noticed there is a big discussion about what is the best build tool e.g. Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, etc. I first opted for Gulp, I read its documentation and started making my first gulpfile.js and it worked I started improving it with the time

But I also noticed that npm can be used as a build tool, I could do the same things I did with my gulp configuration using npm, it took me less time it was just command line instructions, no extra documentation to read.

These are my two configuration files. [gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/donkeysharp/5e31cbb11b5c3700b87f) and [package.json](https://gist.github.com/donkeysharp/8e0bd189e3ea1d8b14b2)

They do almost the same, basic tasks such as concatenation, minifications, transformation from JSX to javascript, etc, one using Gulp and the other using npm. My question is if are there tasks that I could not do with npm only? in the way that will force to use Gulp or another build tool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question infers that npm scripts are less powerful or more constrictive than task runners like Gulp. They're not. With npm scripts you can:

1. Make direct command line calls
2. Reference npm packages in your npm script
3. Call separate JS scripts that leverage any npm packages you may need
4. Call shell scripts, Ruby scripts, Python scripts, and so on.

In short, there's nothing restrictive about npm scripts. So while no technology can do everything, npm scripts are capable of doing everything Gulp and Grunt can do. At their core, npm scripts, Gulp and Grunt are all just opinionated ways to run code.